# Entity Framework Db interceptor creates a log for each item in the query

Tags: entity-framework, logging, entity-framework-6, interceptor

I started using the Dbinterceptor with Entity Framework to trace SQL queries. It works perfect, except it logs for each item in the query. For example: If I do a query like this:

```
context.People.Where(p=>p.Age > 20).ToList()
```

if the query returns 50 items it logs the sql query 50 times.
In my case I need to get only once. How can I achieve that?

Here is my interceptor:

```
internal class EFInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public EFInterceptor(IDataProviderInternal dataProvider)
    {
        this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    IDataProviderInternal dataProvider;
    Guid token = Guid.NewGuid();
    private void Query(string message, bool startLog)
    {
        if (startLog && !dataProvider.QueryStarted)
        {
            dataProvider.QueryStarted = true;
            token = Guid.NewGuid();
            EagleFrameworkEventSource.Log.QueryStarted(token, message);
        }
        else if(!startLog && dataProvider.QueryStarted)
        {
            dataProvider.QueryStarted = false;
            EagleFrameworkEventSource.Log.QueryFinished(token);
        }
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {

        //LogInfo("NonQueryExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}, Parameters: {2}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText, string.Join(",", command.Parameters)));
        Query(String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}, Parameters: {2}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText, string.Join(",", command.Parameters)), false);
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        //LogInfo("NonQueryExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}, Parameters:{2}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText, string.Join(",", command.Parameters)));
        Query(String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}, Parameters:{2}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText, string.Join(",", command.Parameters)),true);
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        //LogInfo("ReaderExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}, Parameters:{2}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText, string.Join(",", command.Parameters)));
        Query(String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}, Parameters:{2}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText, string.Join(",", command.Parameters)),false);
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        //LogInfo("ReaderExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}, Parameters:{2}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText, string.Join(",", command.Parameters)));
        Query(String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}, Parameters:{2}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText, string.Join(",", command.Parameters)),true);
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        //LogInfo("ScalarExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}, Parameters:{2}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText, string.Join(",", command.Parameters)));
        Query(String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}, Parameters:{2}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText, string.Join(",", command.Parameters)),false);
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        //LogInfo("ScalarExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}, Parameters:{2}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText, string.Join(",", command.Parameters)));
        Query(String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}, Parameters:{2}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText, string.Join(",", command.Parameters)), true);
    }

    private void LogInfo(string command, string commandText)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Intercepted on: {0} :- {1} ", command, commandText);
    }
}
```

It seems when the frist query starts it starts the next one before finishes the first one. There fore I added a code to avoid multiple logging, but it seems it is creating a new instance of dataProvider for each item in the query, which is impossible. It seems to acting very funky. Anyone knows what is happening???

Comment: Of course it doesn't do that. Where and how do you register the interceptor?

Comment: @IvanStoev I am registering the interceptor like this: this.DbInterception.Add(interceptor);